# how to "keep" codeigniter activerecord status

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

In my article CURD list, I need to get articles from database using many conditions, after get number of eligible articles(no limit), I need to get first 10 eligible  articles (limit 10). So I want to keep the activerecord status, if it's possible, I don't need to write those 'where' again. Here are my code:

```
//select num
$this->db->select('count(*) as num')
//conditions
$this->db->where/or_where/having/order_by//many conditions...
//get num
$num = $this->db->get('articles')->first_row()->num;
//get articles
$this->db->limit(10);
$articles = $this->db->get('articles')->result();
```

When I finished my first query, the active record status is empty, so the second query is wrong. Is there any way to keep that?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but I was also looking for a way to do this, eventually found the built in solution:

```
// Start of the query you want to re-use
$this->db->start_cache();
//select num
$this->db->select('count(*) as num')
//conditions
$this->db->where/or_where/having/order_by//many conditions...
// End of the query you want to re-use
$this->db->stop_cache();

//get num
$num = $this->db->get('articles')->first_row()->num;
//get articles
$this->db->limit(10);
$articles = $this->db->get('articles')->result();

// Clear the saved query 
$this->db->flush_cache();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no reason why the approach you are taking shouldn't work.  For instance taking your code snippet, tidying up and applying some conditions to it:

```
//select num
$this->db->select('count(*) as num');

//conditions
$this->db->where(array('title' => 'Hello world'));

//get num
$num = $this->db->get('articles')->first_row()->num;

//get articles
$this->db->limit(10);

$articles = $this->db->get('articles')->result();

echo "!".$num."!<br />";
print_r($articles);
exit();
```

Using this within my test application I gather the `$num` result and then a full recordset within `$articles`.

Comment: I use $this->db->last_query() and see there are conditions in the first query, but in the second one, there isn't.

I thought it's because CI clear those conditions to avoid ambiguous query.

BTW， I use CI 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple if clause

```
function get_data($type) {
    //select num
    $this->db->select('count(*) as num')
    //conditions
    $this->db->where/or_where/having/order_by//many conditions...

    //get num
    if($type == 'count')
        return $this->db->get('articles')->first_row()->num;

    //get articles
    if($type == 'articles') {
        $this->db->limit(10);
        return $this->db->get('articles')->result();
    }
}
```

Although I am not sure if there is anything specific for codeigniter that can simplify this, this should work.